# CustomEDID for AMDGPU driver?

Tags: xorg, amd-graphics

Following the instructions of [Headless In-Home Steam Stream Server on Linux - HOW TO](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=680514371&insideModal=0&requirelogin=1), I am trying to "trick" Xorg into thinking a monitor is plugged in when it launches.

I grabbed the EDID config of a standard 1080p monitor this way:

```
$ grep "EDID sections" -A 17 /var/log/Xorg.0.log | cut -c31- | tail -n 16 | sudo tee /etc/X11/pseudomonitor.edid.conf
$ cat /etc/X11/pseudomonitor.edid.conf
00ffffffffffff00410c36c0f33d0000
2014010380341d782eeed5a555489b26
125054bf4b00d1c0b300818001010101
010101010101023a801871382d40582c
450009252100001e000000ff00415535
31303332303135383539000000fc0050
68696c69707320323434450a000000fd
00384c1e5311000a2020202020200177
020324f151020304101f131112222120
05060714151623090707830100006503
0c001000023a801871382d40582c4500
09252100001e8c0ad08a20e02d10103e
9600092521000018011d007251d01e20
6e28550009252100001e8c0ad0902040
31200c40550009252100001800000000
000000000000000000000000000000a3
```

I added this to `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "AMDGPU"
    Driver "amdgpu"
    Option "ConnectedMonitor" "HDMI-1-1"
    Option "CustomEDID" "HDMI-1-1:/etc/X11/pseudomonitor.edid.conf"
EndSection
```

but apparently this option is not available for the amdgpu driver:

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep EDID
[  9991.377] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-3
[  9991.377] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-4
[  9991.377] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-5
[  9991.377] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output HDMI-A-3
[  9991.377] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output DVI-D-0
[  9991.380] (WW) AMDGPU(0): Option "CustomEDID" is not used
```

Any idea if something similar is possible with the AMDGPU driver?

Comment: I'd also like to know this...

Comment: I ended up giving up. I just switch the machine on with a monitor plugged in, then unplug it. It's OK for me since the machine is always on...

Comment: same problem for me, and I would like to know how to solve it